# Word for a parasite except that it has no effect on the host

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking to name a variable. The variable in question contains an object(A) that is favored by the presence of another object(B) but unlike a parasitic or a symbiotic relationship, B is completely unaffected by the presence of A.

Few examples:

Mountain goats live in the mountains. The mountain provides an ecological niche to the goats whereas the goats have no effect on the mountain.

Early human settlements formed around fresh water sources. Proximity to fresh water makes life easier for the humans whereas the early humans have no real effect on the water source.

Comment: Your general description fits the situation where B is a **catalyst** for A, but unfortunately your specific examples don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A host/commensal relationship.

[Commensalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commensalism):

> is a long-term biological interaction (symbiosis) in which members of
>   one species gain benefits **while those of the other species neither
>   benefit nor are harmed.**

Composed of the two:

The **commensal** (the species that benefits from the association) may obtain nutrients, shelter, support, or locomotion from the **host** species, which is substantially unaffected.

en/wikipedia.org

Comment: Perfect answer.